# Deselect choice depending on choice made in a different field

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a radio button choice field (field B) that only shows when a certain previous radio button has been selected in another choice field (field A).

Now, in field B I have two choices, and none of them are selected by default. Depending on which choice is selected, one of two Content fields with some explanatory text will display below. All that works.

The trouble is that when afterwards a different choice is made in field A, field B gets hidden as it should. However, because the user's choice in field B is still selected the associated content field still shows when it shouldn't.

Is there a way to deselect all choices in field B when a different choice is made in field A?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment there is not a way to de-select the choice that an end user has made in a Choice field. This was set up by design, as we do not want to remove a choice that the end user has made on the form.

Comment: Ok, will try and set up the form a different way. Thank you for  your time